# how to echo multidimensional array using foreach?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How to echo multidimensional array using php. curruntly its print only one value but instead of this i want to print all values which is contains in my `$data`

```
  $data = $_POST['allValues'];

            foreach($data as $k=>$v)
            {    
            echo $data[$k][1];
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this :-

```
$data = $_POST['allValues'];

        foreach($data as $key)
        {    
           foreach($key as $value)
           {
               echo $value;
           }
        }
```

Comment: my 'allvalues' contains 4 arrays and the output print 4 times result, i want to print only one time can you please guide me @Asim Raja

Comment: Also please post the output of the code to make it clear to understand.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sam0000/ra5a9reo/  i paste my code here, pls bro help . @Asim Raja

Comment: So you want the sql query to run just once? But then how will you extract the value1,value2 etc?

Comment: happy coding ^^

Answer (score 1):

Use another loop(for/foreach) within your foreach loop.

Depends on keyvalue pair whether to use for or foreach.